# Formatting Java Date and Time in Millis

Tags: java, datetime, date-format

What's a clean, modern way of formatting Java `Date` and `Time` from `System.currentTimeInMillis()` so that the formatting is as follows:

- For `Date`: `YYYY-MM-DD`
- For `Time`: `HH-MM-SS-mmmm`, where `HH` is a 2-digit hour, `MM` is a 2-digit minute, `SS` is a 2-digit second, and `mmm` is a 3-digit millisecond

Looking to get the formatting Date/Time of the current instant (now). Something like:

```
long current = System.currentTimeInMillis();
String formattedDate = getFormattedDateFromCurrent(current);
String formattedTime = getFormattedTimeFromCurrent(current);
```

Don't know if raw Java can do this, or if I have to switch over to something like `joda-time`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried SimpleDateFormat? Does it not work for this?

Comment: Seriously? The class to use comes as first result when googling for "format date in Java"

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I thought about using `SimpleDateFormat` but it doesn't handle time down to milliseconds which is why I thought I might need to switch over to `joda-time`.

Comment: `"I thought about using SimpleDateFormat but it doesn't handle time down to milliseconds"` -- *really*? Are you absolutely sure? Have you reviewed the API?

Comment: I just checked the API, and I see that I was wrong and it does handle milliseconds, however I can only use ":" as the delimiter between the different date/time segments, whereas here I absolutely *need* to use "-", which is what the client is expecting.

Comment: And where did you come up with *that* assumption? Did you actually *try* it?

Comment: Look at the "Examples" section on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page - they clearly denote that "-" isn't supported, only ":" or concatenating all the segments together. Also, @HovercraftFullOfEels - I am here to learn and do not profess to be an expert in anything. If I have asked a strange question, it's because I don't understand it and want to learn better. It hurts my feelings when you describe my question as a "*car accident in slow motion*".

Comment: `"Look at the "Examples" section on this page - they clearly denote that "-" isn't supported, only ":" or concatenating all the segments together."` -- Please indicate where you see this documented as I cant find it in the API. Previous comment deleted, and please accept my apology.

Comment: OK, well, I suppose that you've either solved this and not informed us or have lost interest in this and not informed us.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the long value to the `Date` constructor and it will give you the date.

You can then format this date to get you desired format.

Code to convert to date -

```
long tmp = 1018021774496l;  
Date d = new Date(tmp);  
System.out.println(d);
```

Have a look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/391375/java/java/Convert-long-date). Its the first result in Google ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` is a common tool for formatting date/time in Java. You just need to specify the pattern that you want to represent the date/time.

```
Date now = new Date();
// or you can use
// long millis = System.currentTimeInMillis();
// Date now = new Date(millis);

String datePattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH-MM-SS";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate().toString()
```

> 2016-01-23

…and…

```
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalTime().toString()
```

> 12:34:56.789

## Using java.time

The “clean, modern way” would be using java.time classes.

No need to call `System.currentTimeInMillis()`. The java.time classes can capture the current moment.

If you want the current moment in UTC, use an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

For formatting, morph that into the more flexible `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

To generate strings, you could define a `DateTimeFormatter` object. But in your case, the desired output happens to conform to the standard ISO 8601 formats used by default in the java.time classes.

So, for the date-only portion, use a `LocalDate`. For time-of-day portion, `LocalTime`. Call their `toString` methods.

```
String dateOnly = odt.toLocalDate().toString();
String timeOnly = odt.toLocalTime().toString();
```

### Resolution

Note that while java.time classes resolve to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), capturing the current moment in Java 8 is limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). In Java 9, a new implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) provides capturing the current moment in nanoseconds (or as best your computer clock hardware can provide).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).